# Building WMF (Windows Media Foundation) mediadriver plugin for Qt on Windows 10

Tags: c++, qt, plugins, media, qmediaplayer

I've downloaded and installed the MSVC compiled Qt 5.7 from the [Qt official download page](https://www.qt.io/download-open-source/#section-2) via online installer for Windows 10.

I try to create a media player application that uses [`QVideoProbe`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvideoprobe.html).
Apparently [there are](https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_5.5.0_Multimedia_Backends) two mediadriver plugins (or multimedia backends) for Windows. DirectStreamer and Media Foundation (MF or WMF). Both has some limitations. You can capture video with DirectStreamer but the `QVideoProbe` is not supported. On the WMF side it's on the contrary. You can't use camera capture with WMF but the `QVideoProbe` is supported.

My problem is the Qt comes with DirectStreamer by default.
It can be found at `<qt-install-path>\5.7\msvc2015_64\plugins\mediaservice\dsengine.dll`
I understand that I  have to build and deploy the WMF plugin by myself but I didn't find any documentations or tutorials.

If one downloads the Qt source (also available in the download page) then the source code of the plugin can be found in `<qt-src-path>\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.7.0\qtmultimedia\src\plugins\wmf` directory.

My questions:
How to create this plugin from sorce for an existing Qt install?
Do I need some additional libraries or some other stuff from Windows?
Where can I find some tutorials for this? I did my searching but this (media backend plugin building) seems to be a white spot.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, apparently it was easier than I thought.
Here what was I did:

1. Installed Qt 5.7 with online installer
2. Installed [Visual Studio](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/) and [Debugging Tools For Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463009/)
3. Downloaded source for Qt 5.7 from the [official download page](https://www.qt.io/download-open-source/#section-2)
4. Downloaded and installed QtCreator from the official download page. If the order was correct the IDE automatically recognized the kit (with compiler and debugger).
5. Copied source into Qt directory (into `<qt-install-path>\5.7\src`)
6. Opened `QMultimedia` project with QtCreator (located under `<qt-install-path>\5.7\src\qtmultimedia`)
7. Build `QMultimedia`
8. Build `plugins/wmf` subproject separately

And under the build directory (under `<build-path>\plugins\`) `wmfengine.dll` appeared.